# How to initialize pointers within a struct but the struct is in a module

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, declaration, incomplete-type

maybe it's a stupide question but I can not find a solution. The most answers i found works for structs in the main-file. I want to define the struct (*list*) in a module because some functions in this module work with the struct. Later the struct shoud become the root of a list.

My *module.c* is:

```
#include"modul.h"

struct date{
    int date_date;
};

struct list{
    date *first;
    date *last;
};
```

My *module.h* is:

```
typedef struct date date;
typedef struct list list;
```

In the main.c I try to initialize the two pointers (*first* and *last*) of the struct *list*:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include"module.h"

int main(){
    
    list *mylist=malloc(sizeof(mylist));
    
    mylist->first=NULL;
    mylist->last=NULL;
    
    printf("test");
    
    return 0;
}
```

I try to compile with *gcc*:

```
gcc -Wall -std=c99 main.c module.c -o main
```

and get the following error:

```
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:9:11: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 'list {aka struct list}'
     mylist->first=NULL;
           ^~
```

What did I do wrong? I hope I make the code as simple as possible. With `mylist.first=NULL;` I get also an error.

Comment: You should define your struct in your header file, not the source file.

Comment: You can use this design if you want to define opaque structures, which require the user to use only pointers to the structure and use functions in the module to access the contents. An example is the `FILE` structure in stdio.

Comment: Thanks a lot Christian.

Comment: Some authors consider it a mistake to use `typedef` in this way, see [this discussion](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/process/coding-style.html#typedefs). Even if you don't agree, you should at least be aware.

Comment: in file `module.c` you have the statement: `#include "modul.h"`  There is no header file: `modul.h`!   Perhaps you meant `module.h`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have you struct defined on the .h file.
Also, it's better to define a struct like this:

```c
typedef struct date {
    int date_date;
}DATE;

typedef struct list {
    DATE *first, *last;
}LIST;
```

then on your main you can have:

```c
int main (){
    LIST *mylist = malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    mylist -> first = NULL;
    mylist -> last = NULL;
return 0;
}
```

Also, don't forget to include `stdio.h` in order to use `NULL`.
This method works for me

Answer (score 1):

For starters these declarations

```
struct date{
    int date_date;
};

struct list{
    date *first;
    date *last;
};
```

are wrong and do not make a sense.

For example for this declaration

```
struct list{
    date *first;
    date *last;
};
```

the compiler will issue an error that the type name `date` is not declared. You declared the type `struct date` but not `date`.

But even if you will write correctly

```
struct list{
    struct date *first;
    struct date *last;
};
```

you will not build a list because the structure `date` does not have pointers to next of previous objects of the type `struct date`.

You could declare the structures either like (for singly-linked list)

```
struct date{
    int date_date;
    struct date *next;
};

struct list{
    struct date *first;
    struct date *last;
};
```

or like (for doubly-linked list)

```
struct date{
    int date_date;
    struct date *next;
    struct date *prev;
};

struct list{
    struct date *first;
    struct date *last;
};
```

The file with the function main contains only the header `module.h` that has these declarations of incomplete types

```
typedef struct date date;
typedef struct list list;
```

So the compiler issues an error because when it compiles the translation unit it does not know whether the declared type has data members `first` and `last`.

You should place the complete structure declarations in the header.

For example

```
struct date{
    int date_date;
    struct date *next;
};

struct list{
    struct date *first;
    struct date *last;
};

typedef struct date date;
typedef struct list list;
```

Also there is no great sense to allocate memory dynamically for an object of the type struct list like

```
list *mylist=malloc(sizeof(mylist));
```

that moreover is incorrect.

You could just write

```
list mylist = { .first = NULL, .last = NULL };
```

Comment: @xaxis You need dynamically to allocate nodes of the list but not  an object of the type list that contains only two pointers to nodes.